# Parse non-homogeneous CSV file with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, parsing

I have a CSV file structured like this:

```
# Samples 1
1,58
2,995
3,585

# Samples 2
15,87
16,952
17,256

# Samples 1
4,89
5,63
6,27
```

Is there any way in Python 3.x, how to parse a file structured like this without having to manually go through it line-by-line?

I'd like to have some function, which will automatically parse it considering the labels, like this:

```
>> parseLabeledCSV(['# Samples 1', '# Samples 2'], fileName)
[{1:58,2:995,3:585,4:89,5:63,6:27}, {15:57, 16:952, 17:256}]
```

Comment: What do you mean `parse`, split into columns? There are many python packages specialising in reading in csv data.

Comment: What did you mean by non-homogeneous? The rows look homogeneous to me: each has two integers. Please update your post with what the expected output are. Have you looked into the [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) library module?

Comment: The edit significantly changes the meaning of the question. It was absolutely unclear these were key-value pairs initially.

Comment: @Kupiakos I'm sorry, I hope its clearer now.

Comment: @Eenoku Considering this seems to be a custom format, I'd say the safest bet is to just go line-by-line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

groupby will do all the iterating and grouping for you. In this case, you only care about those contiguous groups of lines that contain a ',' (or are composed only of ',' and digits, or whatever other filter predicate you care to define):

```
input="""# Samples 1
1,58
2,995
3,585

# Samples 2
15,87
16,952
17,256

# Samples 1
4,89
5,63
6,27""".splitlines()

from itertools import groupby
import csv

results = []
for has_comma, data_lines in groupby(input, key=lambda s: ',' in s):
    if has_comma:
        results.append(dict(csv.reader(data_lines)))
```

This can even be collapsed to a single Python list comprehension statement:

```
results = [dict(csv.reader(data_lines)) 
            for has_comma, data_lines in groupby(input, key=lambda s: ',' in s) 
                if has_comma]
```

In both cases, print the results using:

```
for dd in results:
    print(dd)
```

to get:

```
{'1': '58', '3': '585', '2': '995'}
{'15': '87', '17': '256', '16': '952'}
{'5': '63', '4': '89', '6': '27'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
input="""# Samples 1
1,58
2,995
3,585

# Samples 2
15,87
16,952
17,256

# Samples 1
4,89
5,63
6,27"""


def parse(input):
    parsed = {}
    lines = input.split("\n")
    key = "# Unknown"
    for line in lines:
        if line is None or line == "": #  ignore empty line
            continue
        if line.startswith("#") :
            if not parsed.has_key(line):
                parsed[line] = {}
            key = line
            continue
        left, right = line.split(",")
        parsed[key][left] = right
    return parsed


if __name__ == '__main__':
    output = parse(input)
    print(output)
```

will output to:

```
{'# Samples 1': {'1': '58', '3': '585', '2': '995', '5': '63', '4': '89', '6': '27'}, '# Samples 2': {'15': '87', '17': '256', '16': '952'}}
```